# How to pass KVM from local machine to docker container?

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration

I'm trying to launch Android Emulator (aka AVD) in Docker container, by next command

```
docker run -it img_emulator:v1
```

but i get the following error:

```
emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
```

In fact i have virtualization on my laptop with Linux 18.04. I enabled that in Bios and checked it by next command:

```
kvm-ok
```

the system reported:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Probably i have to run my image passing there the KVM with some command something like this:

```
docker run -it img_emulator:v1 --device /dev/kvm
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anybody help me please how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kvm` is a kernel module, so it could be shared by container. Looks you put `--device /dev/kvm` at a wrong command place, the correct is:

```
docker run -idt --device /dev/kvm --name trial ubuntu:18.04
```

Then, copy the `kvm-ok` script from host to container:

```
docker cp /usr/sbin/kvm-ok trial:/opt
```

Finally, verify kvm in container:

```
$ docker exec -it trial /opt/kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Comment: First of all thank you! After docker run command that you advised i get next error: "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"--device\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.  "

Comment: As I said, you may put `--device` at the end of the command line? All things after image name will be treat as image arguments... Could you assure the `--device` in the middle of the command just as I post?

Comment: Yes, I used :   docker run -idt img-emulator:v1 --device /dev/kvm --name trial ubuntu:18.04.4

Comment: Wrong, `img-emulator:v1` here is your image, you specify 2 images here. Maybe next for you: `docker run -idt --device /dev/kvm --name trial2 img-emulator:v1`